# Создание градиента с 4 stop в android xml

Tags: java, android, svg

Я пробовал использовать `mesh gradient` inkscape, но, похоже, он не поддерживается в Android, мне нужно что-то вроде этого:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Градиент с 4 stop для прямоугольника андроида (или любой другой формы, например круга), в основном видно 4 перехода цвета градиента. Как мне это сделать в android?
Или, по крайней мере, чем-то, что поддерживает Android (кроме вывода svg иллюстратора, Inkscape)?

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [making a 4 stop gradient in android's xml](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64027517/7394871) от участника  [@uztcode](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9007093/juztcode).</sub>

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/64027517/7394871

Answer (score 5):

Вы можете приблизить это к исходному изображению, используя несколько градиентов.
Это всего лишь  попытка приблизиться к чему-то. Возможно, вам удастся добиться большего, если немного подправить.

```html
<svg width="250" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
  <defs>
    <linearGradient id="grad1" x1="0" y1="1">
      <stop offset="0" stop-color="rgb(149,254,149)"/>
      <stop offset="1" stop-color="rgb(255,254,149)"/>
    </linearGradient>

    <radialGradient id="grad2" cx="0" cy="0" r="0.75">
      <stop offset="0" stop-color="rgba(254,151,149, 1)"/>
      <stop offset="1" stop-color="rgba(254,151,149, 0)"/>
    </radialGradient>

    <radialGradient id="grad3" cx="1" cy="1" r="0.75">
      <stop offset="0" stop-color="rgba(149,150,202, 1)"/>
      <stop offset="1" stop-color="rgba(149,150,202, 0)"/>
    </radialGradient>
  </defs>
  
  <rect width="100" height="100" fill="url(#grad1)"/>
  <rect width="100" height="100" fill="url(#grad2)"/>
  <rect width="100" height="100" fill="url(#grad3)"/>
</svg>
```

<sub>Свободный перевод  [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64030510/7394871) от участника  [@Paul LeBeau](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1292848/paul-lebeau).</sub>